# Un-Delete AWS S3 file by javascript

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, salesforce

I have to implement the restore functionality of deleted marked files in S3. Is there any way to undo delete or remove delete marker through javascript or REST api.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here, read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the object needs to be [versioned](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectVersioning.html).

To undelete the object, you need to delete the delete marker. You can do this via [HTTP DELETE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RemDelMarker.html) or using the SDK's [DeleteObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectDELETE.html) (here's the [JavaScript SDK equivalent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObject-property)) and supplying the version ID of the delete marker.